# Using MS SQL Server 2005, how can I consolidate detail records into a single comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-concat

**BACKGROUND:**I am running **MS2005**.  I have a MASTER table (ID, MDESC) and a DETAIL table (MID, DID, DDESC) with data as follows

```
1 MASTER_1
2 MASTER_2
1 L1 DETAIL_M1_L1
1 L2 DETAIL_M1_L2
1 L3 DETAIL_M1_L3
2 L1 DETAIL_M2_L1
2 L2 DETAIL_M2_L2
```

If I join the tables with

```
SELECT M.*, D.DID FROM MASTER M INNER JOIN DETAIL D on M.ID = D.MID
```

I get a list like the following:

```
1 MASTER_1 L1
1 MASTER_1 L2
1 MASTER_1 L3
2 MASTER_2 L1
2 MASTER_2 L2
```

**QUESTION:**  Is there any way to use a MS SQL select statement to get the detail records into a comma separated list like this:

```
1 MASTER_1 "L1, L2, L3"
2 MASTER_2 "L1, L2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the concept in the link from Bill Karwin, it's the **CROSS APPLY** that makes it work

```
SELECT ID, DES, LEFT(DIDS, LEN(DIDS)-1) AS DIDS
 FROM MASTER M1 INNER JOIN DETAIL D on M1.ID = D.MID 
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DID + ', '
    FROM MASTER M2 INNER JOIN DETAIL D on M2.ID = D.MID 
    WHERE M1.ID = M2.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ) pre_trimmed (DIDS)
GROUP BY ID, DES, DIDS
```

**RESULTS:**

```
ID  DES        DIDS
--- ---------- ---------------
1   MASTER_1   L1, L2, L3
2   MASTER_2   L1, L2
```

Comment: I agree it is quite slick, although the reliance on XML is a little distrubing but if works well enough without killing performance its a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need a function:-

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DETAIL_LIST]
 (
     @masterid int
 )
 RETURNS varchar(8000)
 AS 
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @dids varchar(8000)

     SELECT @dids = COALESCE(@dids + ', ', '') + DID
     FROM DETAIL
     WHERE MID = @masterid
     RETURN @dids
 END
```

Usage:-

```
SELECT MASTERID, [dbo].[FN_DETAIL_LIST](MASTERID) [DIDS]
FROM MASTER
```

Comment: See posted solution without function ... very slick

Comment: This highlights why its good to specify versions in questions.  APPLY is a SQL 2005 thing.  SQL Servers tend to have a long life and hence in absence of version info I go with a SQL 2000 compatible answer.

Comment: Yes this is a solution I will use due to having SQL Server 2000, thanks

Answer (score 1):

coalesce is your friend.

```
declare @CSL vachar(max)

set @CSL = NULL
select @CSL = coalesce(@CSL + ', ', '') + cast(DID as varchar(8))
from MASTER M INNER JOIN DETAIL D on M.ID = D.MID

select @CSL
```

This will not work well for a generalized query (i.e. works great for a single master record).

You could drop this into a function... but that may not give you the performance you need/want.

Comment: He could wrap something like the above into a function that takes the id from the master table as an input, and returns the comma delimited string.

Comment: Nice, but returns all on one line, like "L1, L2, L3, L1, L2"
I need it grouped by the master rows

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function.  Unfortunately, it's not very easy to duplicate this function in other RDBMS brands that don't support it.

See [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-groupconcat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Thanks for the link, there was some new functionality added to SQL Server with the CROSS APPLY that I never noticed before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function for this to work properly in recent version of SQL Server:

http://sqljunkies.com/WebLog/amachanic/archive/2004/11/10/5065.aspx?Pending=true

Comment: Thanks what I thought as well, but see the pure SQL solution posted